# How to build a tree from this view I have made from 3 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have three tables, related to each other.
Table 1 - Job_Position

1. POR_ID (PK)
2. NAME
3. DESCRIPTION
4. ORG_ID (current_organization ID)

Table 2 - Organizations

1. ORG_ID (current_organization ID) (PK)
2. ID (Text field like XX001, XX002, etc)
3. NAME
4. COD_ORG

Table 3 - ORG_REL

1. ORE_ID (PK)
2. ORG_ID_RELATED_ORGANIZATION ( means current organization ID)
3. ORG_ID (means to parent organization ID)

I have created a view called JOB_ORG with the select:

```
select per_org_rol.por_id as por_id, 
  per_org_rol.name || ' - ' || per_org_rol.description as position_name,
  organizations.id || ' - ' || organizations.name as organization_name,
  per_org_rol.org_id as current_organization,
  org_rel.org_id as parent_organization
  from
  per_org_rol
  join organizations
  on per_org_rol.org_id = organizations.org_id
  join org_rel
  on org_rel.ORG_ID_RELATED_ORGANIZATION =  organizations.org_id;
```

I have tried to create a tree from this view with these values:

1. ID -> POR_ID
2. PARENT_ID -> PARENT_ORGANIZATION
3. NODE_TEXT -> POSITION_NAME
4. START WITH -> PARENT_ORGANIZATION
5. START TREE-> VALUE IS NULL

But no data is shown.
Can anyone provide me with some guidance on this? Thank you

Here is some more information about the structure.

[Image with example structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZdVB.png)

```
CREATE TABLE ORG_REL
(
  ORE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  ORG_ID_RELATED_ORGANIZATION NUMBER NOT NULL,
  ORG_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
)
CREATE TABLE ORGANIZATIONS
(
  ORG_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  ID VARCHAR2(32 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR2(200 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  COD_ORG VARCHAR2(64 BYTE)
)
CREATE TABLE PER_ORG_ROL
(
  POR_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(240 BYTE),
  ORG_ID NUMBER
)




INSERT INTO ORGANIZATIONS (ORG_ID, ID, NAME, COD_ORG)
VALUES (54902, “NY001”, “Master Headquarters”, “NY001”) 
INSERT INTO ORGANIZATIONS (ORG_ID, ID, NAME, COD_ORG)
VALUES (57909, “LEAD”, “Leading”, “NY001LEAD”)
INSERT INTO ORGANIZATIONS (ORG_ID, ID, NAME, COD_ORG)
VALUES (57910, “DIR”, “Principal Director”, “NY001DIR”)
INSERT INTO ORGANIZATIONS (ORG_ID, ID, NAME, COD_ORG)
VALUES (57908, “SUBDIR”, “Sub Director”, “NY001SUBDIR”)
INSERT INTO ORGANIZATIONS (ORG_ID, ID, NAME, COD_ORG)
VALUES (57918, “SECDIR”, “Director Secretary”, “NY001SECDIR”)
INSERT INTO ORGANIZATIONS (ORG_ID, ID, NAME, COD_ORG)
VALUES (67692001, “MARK”, “Marketing Department”, “NY001MARK”)
INSERT INTO ORGANIZATIONS (ORG_ID, ID, NAME, COD_ORG)
VALUES (71683001, “SECMARK”, “Marketing Secretary”, “NY001SECMARK”)
INSERT INTO ORGANIZATIONS (ORG_ID, ID, NAME, COD_ORG)
VALUES (67765001, “DIG”, “Digital Marketing”, “NY001DIG”)
INSERT INTO ORGANIZATIONS (ORG_ID, ID, NAME, COD_ORG)
VALUES (67764001, “TRD”, “Tradicional Marketing”, “NY001TRD”)
INSERT INTO ORGANIZATIONS (ORG_ID, ID, NAME, COD_ORG)
VALUES (67769001, “DIG1”, “Digital Marketing Social Networks”, “NY001DIG1”)
INSERT INTO ORGANIZATIONS (ORG_ID, ID, NAME, COD_ORG)
VALUES (67770001, “DIG2”, “Digital Marketing Google and SEO”, “NY001DIG2”)

INSERT INTO PER_ORG_ROL (POR_ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (“DIR0001”, “Principal Director”, 57910)
INSERT INTO PER_ORG_ROL (POR_ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (“DIR0002”, “SubDirector”, 57908)
INSERT INTO PER_ORG_ROL (POR_ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (“DIR0003”, “Director Secretary”, 57918)
INSERT INTO PER_ORG_ROL (POR_ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (“MARK0001”, “Head of Marketing Department”, 67692001)
INSERT INTO PER_ORG_ROL (POR_ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (“MARK0002”, “Secretary of Marketing Department”, 71683001)
INSERT INTO PER_ORG_ROL (POR_ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (“DIG0001”, “Head of Digital Marketing”, 67765001)
INSERT INTO PER_ORG_ROL (POR_ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (“DIG1001”, “Head of Digital Marketing Social Networks”, 67769001)
INSERT INTO PER_ORG_ROL (POR_ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (“DIG1002”, “Worker_1”, 67769001)
INSERT INTO PER_ORG_ROL (POR_ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (“DIG1003”, “Worker_2”, 67769001)
INSERT INTO PER_ORG_ROL (POR_ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (“DIG2001”, “Head of Digital Marketing Google and SEO”, 67770001)
INSERT INTO PER_ORG_ROL (POR_ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (“DIG2002”, “Worker_1”, 67770001)
INSERT INTO PER_ORG_ROL (POR_ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (“TRD0001”, “Head of Tradicional Marketing”, 67764001)

INSERT INTO ORG_REL (ORG_ID_RELATED_ORGANIZATION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (57909, 54902)
INSERT INTO ORG_REL (ORG_ID_RELATED_ORGANIZATION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (57910, 57909)
INSERT INTO ORG_REL (ORG_ID_RELATED_ORGANIZATION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (57908, 57909)
INSERT INTO ORG_REL (ORG_ID_RELATED_ORGANIZATION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (57918, 57910)
INSERT INTO ORG_REL (ORG_ID_RELATED_ORGANIZATION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (67692001, 57908)
INSERT INTO ORG_REL (ORG_ID_RELATED_ORGANIZATION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (71683001, 67692001)
INSERT INTO ORG_REL (ORG_ID_RELATED_ORGANIZATION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (67765001, 67692001)
INSERT INTO ORG_REL (ORG_ID_RELATED_ORGANIZATION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (67764001, 67692001)
INSERT INTO ORG_REL (ORG_ID_RELATED_ORGANIZATION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (67769001, 67765001)
INSERT INTO ORG_REL (ORG_ID_RELATED_ORGANIZATION, ORG_ID)
VALUES (67770001, 67765001)
```

Comment: I'm happy to give it a try - pls update your question with minimal ddl and some dml so I can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Koen, thank you. I added the information you request and hope it is explanatory.

Comment: Did you run those statements yourself (hint... I'm pretty sure you didn't) ? There are no semi colons after each statements, there is a trailing comma in the first DDL statement before the closing bracket, the inserts into SQL per_org_col fail with Error: ORA-00947: not enough values, the inserts into org_rel fail with ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into and the double quotes are some weird ascii character that probably comes from copying from a windows application (use single quotes instead pls). Please verify and run your own code before asking others to run it...

Comment: No, I have not. I am sorry. This is information I have constructed from an excel sheet after I have manually copied it from the database. I will correct it. I am sorry.I am still a noob on this...